# Can we find a way to identify brand specific expertise?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I'm relatively new to this Stack Exchange site, but I've participated on several others over time. The few questions I've looked at and responded to so far have been Jeep Wrangler related, because that's what I know.

In reading many of the other answers, it's clear the person answering has some related knowledge, but not specific to Jeep or Jeep Wrangler, therefore the answer is slightly off the mark.

I don't know if it's feasible, or reasonable, but perhaps we can find a way to recognize people that have demonstrated expertise with a specific brand or model of vehicle? I don't know if that's in the form of brand specific reputation or perhaps as badges.

For example, perhaps someone who earns 100 reputation points responding to Jeep related questions (or Honda, car audio, tires), using tags as a reference, could earn a badge for knowledge related to that tag.

Someone might have 2000 reputation earned responding to Honda tuning questions, but that doesn't mean they know about transfer cases and steering geometry.

Comment: Hit us up at [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop). We tend to know who's knowledgeable about what.

Comment: You seem to have some killer model specific knowledge about Jeeps.  Please come around more!   As @Zaid  said above, come by chat and share the wealth!  There are some Jeep questions on here that really need you.  Cheers!

Comment: @DucatiKiller thank you for that. I noticed you upvoted a number of my answers. I appreciated it. I tend to access the site with the Stack Exchange app on my tablet, and for some reason, i couldn't comment on this post from the app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, it already exists. They are called "tag badges". For instance, two days ago I was awarded the gold tag badge for [engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine), which means I have accumulated 1000 upvotes (not points) in questions which have the engine tag associated with it. I have had to answer at least 200 questions in order to qualify for the badge. There are two other badges which are earned along the same line, which are the bronze (100 upvotes/20 answers), and silver (400 upvotes/80 answers).

If you as an answerer want to figure out who might have specific knowledge, there are two primary ways you might be able to suss this out.

First, you can find someone with a lot of experience in a certain badge by looking up who was awarded the badge for a given tag. You'd need to look in the [bronze category](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), as there are only two silver badges awarded, and only one gold (at the time of this writ).

Second, stick around and see who answers what. If there is a motorcycle question, the first person I turn to is DucatiKiller. He was an MC mechanic for many years and has a great appreciation for them. If there's a body question, I will send a nod to Jonathan Musso, who has great skills in that arena. I consider myself a generalist. I know quite a bit about a lot of different subjects, but don't consider myself an expert in any one area. I have a knack for asking the right questions of people who don't know much about cars to get the information needed to help them figure out what's going on. Don't get me wrong, I've done a lot of wrenching. You can usually ask me a question and I'll have some sort of answer for it or I can hunt it down on the Interwebz (my GoogleFu is strong!). The only way you would know *any of this* is if you stick around and get to know some of the guys on here ... I use "guys" in a generic sense. We have a few gals which frequent as well ... this is not a "good ole boys" thing, lol!

I hope this helps you out a little bit and actually gives you what you are looking for. If not, please clarify what you're asking and I'll see if I have an answer for you.

Answer (score 5):

I really like your question.

There are some mechanisms built into the SE framework that @paulster2 mentioned that I would like to clarify.

- There are badges that reflect disciplines.
- They are based upon [tags](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags)
- When a metric is hit related to tags a bronze, silver or gold badge is awarded to the responder for participating in so many questions and answers related to that tag.
- Here is a list of [badges awarded for tags](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags)

So, there is a mechanism for this component.  As the site grows and more resources become a part of the community more detailed manufacturer and model expertise will grow.  I've witnessed this over time and see the trend continuing with newer members.

Comment: Shouldn't your link for "badges awarded for tags" point here? http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it matters, my strong brands are Toyota (include old school), Mustangs (Fox and newer), Porsche 911 (SC, 930, 993, 964), Ferrari, and Jeeps. I also know about engine specifics, turbocharging, nitrous, and carburetors. Can program Tec3, Motul, and pretty much every aftermarket computer. Since I'm also a systems engineer with lots of hardware experience I can pretty much build any type of electronics. Also do composites pretty well (for not having an autoclave). So yeah, I guess if you need help with that just ping me somehow.